# Microsoft Access Update Queries

Tags: ms-access-2013

Let me start by saying that I am indeed self-taught and I have no business trying to do what I am trying to do...However, I am combining two Access databases that track different information about the same projects (one tracks the proposal information for projects considered for selection and the other tracks budget information for those that are selected).  The same projects have different IDs in each database.  Each database has lookup fields (yeah, yeah, I know lookup fields are evil, but that is what I have). I want to update the values in the lookup fields for the related tables in the Budget DB to the ID fields for the same projects in the Project DB. Is there a way to write an update query to change the value in the project ID field of one table to the ID fields from another table?

Details: ProjectListTbl contains ProjectID field and the BudgetID field which refers to project ID from the Budget database (BDBID).  I want the Reporting table values to change from the Budget Database ID (BDBProjectID) to the ProjectID from the ProjectListTbl.  I have tried

UPDATE Reporting INNER JOIN ProjectListTbl ON ReportingTbl.BDBProjectID = ProjectListTbl.ProjectID SET ReportingTbl.BDBProjectID = [ProjectListTbl].[ProjectID], WHERE (((ReportingTbl.BDBProjectID)=DLookUp([ProjectListTbl].[ProjectID],[ProjectListTbl],[BudgetID]=[ReportingTbl]![BDBProjectID])));

Comment: I would first create a select statement based on your join conditions.  Once you are sure that things are matching up properly, then make it an update statement. The proper order of commands in an update statement should be UPDATE, SET, INNER JOIN, WHERE.

Comment: Thank you for that advice.  I did the Select query and discovered that my logic about my lookup field was faulty.  I am going to have to think on that for a bit before figuring out how to go forward.